# wxpython panel size and titles

Tags: python, wxpython, size, panel

When I apply the following code, the second panel is showed over the first one. I would like to know how I can get the two panels without overlapping and with the appropriate size of the window (frame). I would also like to know if there is any suitable way to draw some kind of titles in a panel (in this case, "Inputs:" and "Outputs:"). Thanks!

```
import wx

class Input_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        # Input variables
        self.tittle1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Inputs:")    
        self.lblname1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Input 1:")
        self.format1 = ['Option 1','Option 2']
        self.combo1 = wx.ComboBox(self, size=(200, -1),value='', choices=self.format1, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
        self.lblname2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Input 2")
        self.format2 = ['Option 1','Option 2', 'Option 3']
        self.combo2 = wx.ComboBox(self, size=(200, -1),value='', choices=self.format2, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        # Set sizer for the panel content
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(2, 2)
        self.sizer.Add(self.tittle1, (1, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname1, (2, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.combo1, (2, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname2, (3, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.combo2, (3, 2))
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

class Output_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        # Output variables
        self.tittle2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Outputs:")    
        self.lblname3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Output1")
        self.result3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="", size=(100, -1))

        # Set sizer for the panel content
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(2, 2)
        self.sizer.Add(self.tittle2, (1, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname3, (2, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.result3, (2, 2))
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

class Main_Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title)

        # Set variable panels
        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.panel1 = Input_Panel(self.splitter)
        self.panel2 = Output_Panel(self.splitter)
        self.splitter.SplitVertically(self.panel1, self.panel2)

        self.windowSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.windowSizer.Add(self.splitter, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)   
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.windowSizer)

def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main_Window(None, "App GUI")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying

```
self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
```

by

```
self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
```

into Input_Panel and output_Panel classes also resizes panels correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Widget Inspection Tool to help you figure out what's going on. I used its highlight functionality to figure out where and what size each of the panels were. You can read more about it here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool

The SplitterWindow does not split items equally. You will need to call the splitter's SetMinimumPaneSize to make them both visible. I modified your code to show you what I'm talking about and also to demonstrate how to add the inspection tool:

```
import wx

class Input_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        # Input variables
        self.tittle1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Inputs:")    
        self.lblname1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Input 1:")
        self.format1 = ['Option 1','Option 2']
        self.combo1 = wx.ComboBox(self, size=(200, -1),value='', choices=self.format1, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
        self.lblname2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Input 2")
        self.format2 = ['Option 1','Option 2', 'Option 3']
        self.combo2 = wx.ComboBox(self, size=(200, -1),value='', choices=self.format2, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        # Set sizer for the panel content
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(2, 2)
        self.sizer.Add(self.tittle1, (1, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname1, (2, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.combo1, (2, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname2, (3, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.combo2, (3, 2))
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

class Output_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        # Output variables
        self.tittle2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Outputs:")    
        self.lblname3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Output1")
        self.result3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="", size=(100, -1))

        # Set sizer for the panel content
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(2, 2)
        self.sizer.Add(self.tittle2, (1, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname3, (2, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.result3, (2, 2))
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

class Main_Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size=(800,600))

        # Set variable panels
        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style = wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        self.panel1 = Input_Panel(self.splitter)
        self.panel2 = Output_Panel(self.splitter)
        self.splitter.SplitVertically(self.panel1, self.panel2)
        w, h = self.GetSize()
        self.splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(w/2)

        self.windowSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.windowSizer.Add(self.splitter, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)   

        #self.SetSizerAndFit(self.windowSizer)

def main():
    import wx.lib.inspection
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main_Window(None, "App GUI")
    frame.Show()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked, but I would like to know if it is possible to set different sizes for each panel. In the extended code, the right panel is much smaller than the left one and looks not very well when using "self.splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(120)". And is it possible to add a title as I asked before?

Comment: I would actually use the frame's size and then set the pane size to be half of that to get them equal. As for the title, you would have to use a StaticText widget or similar

Comment: I know I want too much, but can I ask you for an example?

Comment: You already have the title thing figured out, so I just updated the code to use the size of the frame to size the panels

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't express myself correctly. I don't want the panes show the same size. I want the left one bigger than the right one, but still both need to be seen completely. It seems that SetMinimumPaneSize affects both panes equally.

Comment: This is pretty old, but should give you one approach: http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProportionalSplitterWindow. Alternatively, you can set the sash position which may be what you want. This thread also talks about using sizers to better control how panels are shown/sized: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/3GDq7ofmxPw